# Internet Explorer 10 doesn't seem to work with Sysinternals Desktops

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, sysinternals

I heavily use [Sysinternals Desktops version 2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) to manage multiple desktops.  In the past, I used Internet Explorer 9 as this was the only web browser I found that could function across multiple desktops.  However, I've upgraded to IE10 on Windows 7 and now I can't seem to open IE across multiple desktops.

The same issue is noted by someone else here, but no solution was found:  http://forum.sysinternals.com/desktops-v2-broken-by-win8-or-win7-with-ie10_topic29162.html

Non-starter answers are to use other multi-desktop apps that do not use use multiple [Windows desktop objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I find other solutions involving showing/hiding windows to be slow/unreliable.

Is there a way to get any of the major web browsers working simultaneously on multiple Windows desktop objects, such as used by Sysinternals Desktops?

Comment: You will have to wait until the application is updated to support IE10.  You don't get to eliminate solutions that can solve the problem you face for other people.  Just because those other tools are not an option for **YOU** doesn't meant hey are not possible solutions for other people.

Comment: @Ramhound: Then what, exactly, are you proposing?  The problem is that IE10 doesn't support multiple Windows desktop objects any more; Sysinternals Desktops is just a thin wrapper around a public Windows API.

Comment: How have you determined that IE10 no longer supports multiple Windows desktop objects.  Its unlike Microsoft to discontinue support for something like this without notice.

Comment: @Ramhound: If you think it still does, can you help me out instead of downvoting me? (if you were the downvoter)  I was unable to locate any statement from Microsoft about this, and my experience has matched that of the person on the Sysinternals forum: the browser only opens on one desktop at a time now - attempts to launch a new browser on another desktop just open a new window on the first desktop, oddly enough.  I also wonder why you deleted some of the tags for my question, even though they are applicable?  The deleted tags are more general and have more followers than the ones you left.

Comment: You are using Windows 7 and IE10 your problem is isolated to those conditions. If you read the descriptions of those tags they should only be used if the problem applies to ALL versions of IE and ALL versions of Windows which your problem does not.  I would contact Mark Russinovich who has a blog who can answer the reason this bug exists.

Comment: @Ramhound: For starters, the problem is reported on Windows 8 as well, so it really applies to multiple Windows versions.  Do you really expect questions with general tags to apply to ALL released versions of Windows and IE?  What about older versions from the 90s like Windows 3.1, Internet Explorer 2.0?  Why don't you start untagging all those questions in those categories?  I bet most of them don't even make sense in the context of older versions of Windows/IE, so you should untag them!

Comment: @Ramhound:  Do you expect users to test their problem on EVERY combination of released Windows and IE versions?  E.g. require testing on Windows 3.x, Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows NT4, Windows NT3.x, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, etc.  And IE1, IE2, IE3, IE4, IE5, IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10....  You are imposing onerous requirements that nobody is actually following.  On StackOverflow, people use both general and specific tags and nobody cares much.  Instead, we just answer questions and help people rather than fuss!

Comment: So change the tags back if you feel so strongly about my modifications.  You made no reference to the problem existing on Windows 8.  You said you were using Windows 7 and upgraded to Internet Explorer 10.  **You shouldn't tag a question with generic tags just because they have more followers.**  **I also stand by my tag modification per the descriptions of those generic tags.**

Comment: Wow guys was there a need for the bold and Caps? :) Good discussion otherwise... am trying to edit my related question and vote for duplicate. The text in the links seems very useful in order to make a decision on my question being a subsequent duplicate which is only specified to Chrome... but seems the problem is general. http://superuser.com/q/863672/106227

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An old question but it still shows up on Google, so:

The solution is to add the "-noframemerging" switch to the internet explorer shortcut.

Clicking the shortcut will now open IE in the current Desktop window (albeit more slowly than normal).

Comment: I need to return to this option for the Chrome version of the problem. Hopefully still have 8 on my horse at home. http://superuser.com/q/863672/106227

Comment: dlott has posted an answer for Chrome version of the problem - http://superuser.com/a/905335/106227