# SysInternals Desktops not launching Chrome

Tags: sysinternals

I'm using Desktops from SysInternals on Windows 8 and experiencing a problem launching Chrome. Even if I go to the exe of Chrome it will not launch in anything but the first Desktop. Does anyone know why that might occur?

Comment: Seems like Desktops isn't fully working on Windows 8 for multiple different browers. Another post about IE provides some clues (http://superuser.com/q/586284/106227). Launching instances of all browsers had trouble as at 2013 - http://forum.sysinternals.com/desktops-v2-broken-by-win8-or-win7-with-ie10_topic29162.html

Comment: You will have to use some other programs besides Desktops if you want to add this functionality to Windows 8.  The program has not been updated in nearly 3 years which indicates its unlikely to be updated to support any incompatibilities that might exist with Windows 8.

Answer (score 17):

This is an issue in Chrome.  A workaround is to use a unique user profile per desktop

`"chrome.exe --user-data-dir=<insert unique dir here>"`

See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2730#c14 for more info.